# Ruby's .match method always returning true

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

Can someone tell me why this method is always returning true, even when the string does not match the pattern? I've ran the regex through TextWrangler's regex engine, and the pattern is correct. Thanks

```
def validatePEM pem
 if /^-{4}([-\s])BEGIN/.match(pem)
   print "validatePEM found a match\n"
   return true
 else
   return false
  end
end
@s = '---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'


if validatePEM @s
  print "VALID PEM FILE\n"
else
  print "INVALID PEM FILE\n"
end
```

Comment: I can't tell you, but your pattern does not what you think it does. `[...]` is a character class, matching any of the characters inside. No need for additional parentheses or pipes: `/^[-]{4}[\s-]BEGIN/` (note you don't *have* to escape hyphens in character classes if they are the last character in the class - but that's a matter of taste)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the escaped hyphens

Comment: They are not the issue. I realize now that I wasn't quite clear. It's not that there is "no need" for parentheses and pipes. You must not include them. Because, if you do, the character class will match a literal parenthesis or a literal pipe, too. And about your new regex. It does the same as mine, it is just highly redundant. `{1}` never changes anything (under no circumstances). And `([-]|\s)` is the same as `[\s-]`. Also note that `\s` matches tabs and line breaks, too. Not only spaces.

Comment: Besides whether it works, or not, you should keep the code as simple as possible. `[-]` should be changed to `-`, and `{1}` should be removed since it does nothing, and `(|)` should be changed to `[]`. The regex would then be `/^-{4}[-\s]BEGIN/`.

Comment: Was not aware that Ruby differs from other languages in that it automatically uses "multiline mode", This was causing the regex to find other instances on subsequent lines so by changing "^" to "\A" anchored to the first line of the string, giving the expected tresults

Comment: The code sample isn't valid Ruby. The `validatePEM` method is unterminated, and `\A[-]{4}([-\s])BEGIN/` is an invalid regex.

Comment: My bad - I missed the last "end" when I pasted. Thanks for pointing it out. Not sure why you said the regex is invalid, Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: You changed the regex when you updated your code. The version in my previous comment was in the question previously, and is not correct because it is missing the leading `/`.

Comment: Ah ha. I need to slow down, some. Thanks

Comment: It's important that you make sure your question's text, and sample code and data accurately reflect your reality. Remember, you're asking us to take time from our day to help you.

Comment: Agreed and much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a FYI, there are several things done in "un-Ruby" ways.

I'd write:

```
def validatePEM pem
if /\A-{4}([-\s])BEGIN/.match(pem)
  print "validatePEM found a match\n"
  return true
else
  return false
  end
end
@s = '---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'


if validatePEM @s
  print "VALID PEM FILE\n"
else
  print "INVALID PEM FILE\n"
end
```

something like:

```
def validatePEM(pem)
  !!pem[/\A-{4}([\s-])BEGIN/]
end

@s = '---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

puts '%s PEM FILE' % (validatePEM(@s) ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID')
```

The use of a ternary statement for printing is something that some might question when writing in Ruby, but the [Ruby Style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) agrees that writing trivial conditional tests with ternary (`?:`) is OK.

Comment: Wow, that is really nice, especially the method implementation